# Correlation analysis in R, where data consists of both continous and categorical variables

Tags: correlation

I have microbiome data from metaphlan. For instance I have 20 samples as rows and about 50 different species as column and relative abundance data about those. The second dataframe consists of metadata regarding these samples. Once again samples as rows, and column include age (continous), day of sample (continous), height (continous), probiotic (yes or no - categorical), antibiotic (yes or no - categorical).

I read a bit online and I understand that correlation matrix can be made for continous variables using spearman correlation. But what happens in case of categorical variables? Is is safe to convert them to binary values and use them in spearman?

Or should one perform correlation analysis twice: once using spearman with continous data and second with kendall or cramersv using categorical data?

I am trying to generate a correlation matrix and plot using heatmap for visualisation in R.
For Spearman I tried this:
correlation.table <- associate(taxa, metadata_edited, method = "spearman", p.adj.threshold = 0.05,
mode = "table")

```
p <- heat(correlation.table, "X2", "X1", 
      fill = "Correlation",  p.adj.threshold = 0.05,
      star = "p.adj") 

p
```

But this is just for continous data, how to deal with categorical?

Any help would be appreciated.